# Google K8s Mirror offline?

Tags: kubernetes

Heys dudes,

More someone got error when trying update cache of the Google K8s repositories?
I have been got the error about **NO_PUBKEY**

```
Err:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease        
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6A030B21BA07F4FB Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
```

and

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6A030B21BA07F4FB Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6A030B21BA07F4FB Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Something was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired):

> On Debian and Ubuntu based systems, including your local workstations,
> you might encounter an error similar to the following example:
> [...] The following signatures were invalid: XXXX [...]

To resolve this error, get the latest valid `apt-key.gpg` key file from `https://packages.cloud.google.com` by running the following command:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: My doubt was this if the key was changed or something more deep. Valeu Du.